# Change the RLIMIT_NPROC in linux

Tags: linux

I;m trying to find a way to change the RLIMIT_NPROC value in my RedHat linux machine. So far I wasn't able to find a proper way to do so. Is there a simple way to change it without using c/c++ , just by using the command line or editing a specific file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at `/etc/security/limits.conf` or `/etc/security/limits.d/` if the latter exists in your installation. Don't forget to re-login afterward

Answer (score 3):

the classic linux command to handle this was *ulimit.*

recently it has been superceded by *getrlimit, setrlimit* and *sysconf*

your distro may have specific config files ususally in /etc/security/limits.conf